# C Header Files not installed in Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, sdl

I have been trying to compile SDL 2.0.1 in Linux. I found the problem and the problem is that I don't have C header files installed in my /usr/include directory. Anyone know of a solution to install the header files to my system?

GCC 4.7 and build-essentials are already installed by the way.

Comment: they are in /usr/include, /usr/local/include has the files installed by the user

Comment: sorry, my bad. I wrote the wrong directory.

Comment: Which distribution? Which exact headers? For glibc, install something like `libc6-dev` on debian based systems.

Comment: keltar, I'm using Xubuntu 13.04, will upgrade to 13.10 soon. The headers missing are all the standard C headers like stdio.h, malloc.h, stdlib.h. However, the all the standard C++ headers are installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the `-dev` versions of the packages SDL needs. For example on Debian and Ubuntu, you'd need stuff like libasound2-dev, libpulse-dev, libaudio-dev, libx11-dev, and a lot of others.

In order to get most of them automatically, try to install the dev package of SDL 1.2. This will pull-in the other packages as dependencies. They're mostly the same with SDL 2.